# Inserting XML node at specific position

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

I have an XML file and I am loading it in Xmldocument. This document has a node with some child nodes like this

```
<xml here>
 <somenode>
   <child> </child>
   <children></children>
   <children></children>
   <children></children>  // I need to insert it
   <children></children>  // I need to insert this second time
   <children></children>
   <children></children>
   <child> </child>
 <somenode>
<xml here>
```

here somenode has some children where first and last children node names are same where as other nodes except the first and last node has some diffrent name ( identical to each other ). I am creating a function to insert a node at specific position, I am not sure about the criteria but may be in the mid.

- how can I insert node in specific position. I am using XMLnode.appendChild method for insertion
- Do I need to rearrange/sort nodes after insertion. Please suggest.
- How can I determine what is structure and how should I find where the new node should be added according to current document structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use XLinq to [modify XML document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/04/04/linq-to-xml-modifying-xml-document.aspx)

Following is an example of xml modification

```
    String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"+"<xmlhere>"+
    "<somenode>"+
    " <child> </child>"+
    " <children>1</children>"+ //1
    " <children>2</children>"+ //2
    " <children>3</children>"+ // 3, I need to insert it
    " <children>4</children>"+  //4,  I need to insert this second time
    " <children>5</children>"+
    " <children>6</children>"+ 
    " <child> </child>"+
    " </somenode>"+
    "</xmlhere>";

    XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
    var childrens = root.Descendants("children").ToArray();
    var third = childrens[3];
    var fourth = childrens[4];
    third.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("children"));
    fourth.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("children"));

    var updatedchildren = root.Descendants("children").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution **without using LINQ to XML**. It's implemented as an extension method for the `XmlNode` class:

```C#
public static void InsertAt(this XmlNode node, XmlNode insertingNode, int index = 0)
{
    if(insertingNode == null)
        return;
    if (index < 0)
        index = 0;

    var childNodes = node.ChildNodes;
    var childrenCount = childNodes.Count;

    if (index >= childrenCount)
    {
        node.AppendChild(insertingNode);
        return;
    }

    var followingNode = childNodes[index];

    node.InsertBefore(insertingNode, followingNode);
}
```

Now, you can insert a node at the desired position as simple as:

```C#
    parentXmlNode.InsertAt(childXmlNode, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/55428/how-to-insert-xml-child-node-programmatically.aspx
Cheack it!I guess it will help u.

Comment: try to get all childs to collection and after that set value